# SPARQL - How to count wiki PageOutDegree for specific subject?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to do SPARQL query to get a number value for wiki PageOutDegree property for specific subject, for example for Chicago city.

I also would like to know how to get number of wiki PageOutDegree for all subject of type "City". Is there a way to count them all?

And what about InDegree? Is there a way to get them also?

Thank you guys, I am really confused from this :/

Comment: that data (`http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageOutDegree`) isn't loaded into the current public DBpedia endpoint. you can download the data and process locally.

Comment: Or you use the graph `http://dbpedia.org/page_links` and count via SPARQL - indeed this is slower like querying the precomputed values. Example: `select (count(*) as ?cnt) where {dbr:Chicago ?p ?o} ` - don't forget to use the correct graph

Comment: Ah... Ok. And what about cs.dbpedia.org - there is loaded http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageOutDegree ... I can select amount of wikiPageOutDegree for every city saved in dataset, but how to count up those values to one final result?

Select ?subject xsd:Integer(?object)
{
?subject dbpedia-owl:wikiPageOutDegree ?object.
?subject rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City>.
}

Comment: well, but this is **not** the English DBpedia data then but the Czech DBpedia - which in fact is based on the English Wikipedia - totally different datasets for sure.

Comment: I don't get the meaning of summing page counts even for class ranking, but indeed `sum` function would do the trick: `Select sum(?object) { ?subject dbpedia-owl:wikiPageOutDegree ?object. ?subject rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City>. }`

Comment: Wau... so simply .. I didnt know about sum function. Better I study Sparql 1.1 I think ... Thank you man!

Comment: don't forget to add it as an answer here and "accept" it such that the question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum(?object) 
  { ?subject dbpedia-owl:wikiPageOutDegree ?object. 
    ?subject rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City>. }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the rationale of your answer, and how it works?